# Как сделать подкатегории для каждой категории в Django?

Tags: python, django

**Всем привет.** Есть категории в отдельном классе models.py, также написал отдельный класс для подкатегории. Все это закинул в admin.py, создал категории, и для каждой категории создал подкатегорий. Во views.py ничего больше не добавлял. Так вот, нужно ли написать для подкатегорий во views.py? И если нет, то как вывести в шаблоне с моделей? Еще можно ли сделать все это не создавая класс подкатегории в models.py?

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    img = models.FileField(verbose_name='Фото категории')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Название')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        ordering = ['name']

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, verbose_name='Название')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'ПодКатегории'
        verbose_name = 'ПодКатегория'
        ordering = ['name']
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    softs = Soft.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'softs': softs, 'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

**В этом я пока что новичок, так что строго не судите. И всем кто отозвался, заранее спасибо.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли сделать все это не создавая класс подкатегории в models.py?

Нужно! Потому что подкатегорий может быть больше одной. Удобно использовать связь `ForeignKey` на ту же самую модель, указав `self` первым аргументом.

***models.py:***

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

***views.py:***

```py
categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
```

***template.html:***

```py
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for subcategory in category.category_set.all %}
        {{ subcategory }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: nomnoms12, Все сделал как вы сказали, добавил все это в admin.py, после добавления перешел на главную страницу и получил такую ошибку: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCmGL.png

Comment: Это были 2 разных ответа) Один ответ по поводу того, как использовать Ваши текущие модели, а второй — как лучше их переделать. Сейчас добавлю пример шаблона к первому ответу.

Comment: Вот как)), хорошо, спасибо за ответы)

Comment: Извините, я немного ошибся в ответах, уже исправил код. Попробуйте теперь один из вариантов.

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо большое за ваши ответы!)

Comment: Да, все уже хорошо работает)

Answer (score 0):

> Как вывести [подкатегории] в шаблоне с моделей?

Через [`ForeignKey.related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

***template.html:***

```py
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for subcategory in category.subcategory_set.all %}
        {{ subcategory }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```